# Revision tab is not listing any revision

Tags: nodes, 8

I have the Node revision module (**diff**) installed, and I have many revisions for a node, but the *Revision* tab is not showing any of them, even though the database table contains the data for those revisions.

What may the reason be?

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

A core issue related to languages was just fixed today: [NodeController::revisionOverview() shows no revisions if node has no translation for current language](https://www.drupal.org/node/2713587)

However, since you use diff, which replaces that patch and does its own thing, it might be the same or a similar bug there. Create an issue, possibly reference to the core issue.